# How to make Emacs mouse drag not highlight or set mark

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I hold down mouse-1 and move it around in a buffer, I just want the cursor to follow the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the original question:

```
  (defun my-move-cursor (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (mouse-set-point event)
  (let (event ov)
    (track-mouse
      (while (progn
               (setq event (read-event))
               (or (mouse-movement-p event)
                   (memq (car-safe event) '(switch-frame select-window))))
        (mouse-set-point event)
        (if ov (move-overlay ov (point)  (1+ (point)))
          (setq ov (make-overlay (point) (1+ (point))))
          (overlay-put ov 'face 'match))))
    (when ov (delete-overlay ov))))
```

What I ended up doing was a bit different. I modified the normal function so it does not enable transient-mark-mode, and made a constant overlay which highlights the character that the mouse is on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

`(global-unset-key [drag-mouse-1])`

`(global-unset-key [down-mouse-1])`

**Notice**: There is problem in this method that the mouse does not follow your mouse. Though the cursor will go when you release your mouse.

Looking forward a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variant on Ian Kelling's solution which doesn't use overlays, but controls the cursor blinking, disables any transient mark that is currently active, and avoids problems with mousing out of the Emacs window:

```
(defun my-move-cursor (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (deactivate-mark)
  (mouse-set-point event)
  (let ((blinking (if blink-cursor-mode 1 0)))
    (blink-cursor-mode 0)
    (let (event)
      (track-mouse
    (while (progn
         (setq event (read-event))
         (mouse-movement-p event))
      (ignore-errors (mouse-set-point event)))
    ))
    (blink-cursor-mode blinking))
  )
```

I combine this definition with the following mouse remappings in my init file:

```
; Set up mouse 1 movement
(global-set-key [drag-mouse-1] 'mouse-set-point)
(global-set-key [down-mouse-1] 'my-move-cursor)

; Set up mouse 3 behavior to emulate standard mouse 1 behavior
(global-set-key [down-mouse-3] 'mouse-drag-region)
(global-set-key [drag-mouse-3] 'mouse-set-region)
```